# Having problems to become root

Tags: su

I'm trying to become root, a thing that worked perfectly some days away and now won't work. I type in the terminal

```
su -sudo
```

then the system ask me about the password, and then appears this message:

```
su: failed to execute udo: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is your OS? You probably meant to type `sudo su -` rather than `su -sudo` (although in many Linux flavors, `sudo su -` is deprecated in favor of `sudo -i`)

Comment: Your command, as written, is trying to log you in a the user `sudo`. Try the command `sudo -i` instead.

Comment: @steeldriver How to you manage to beat me out on comments by less than a minute on so many questions? :)

Comment: @doneal24 I dunno - the devil makes work for idle hands I guess ;) BTW the OPs command would attempt to log in as root but run a *shell* named `udo` I think?

Comment: @steeldriver, this is definately true. `su -sudo` cmd will try to login as root but with "`udo`" shell - thus error `No such file or directory`.

Comment: @Damir I would have expected a mandatory space between `-s` and its argument. Just tested and the space is optional. Is `udo` a new shell that I've never heard of?

Comment: @doneal24, no `udo` is not new shell and you are right, space is optional. Just try `su -s/bin/bash` and you will see, everything will be ok. You will be prompted for password (by default) and you will get your root shell session. Of course if you don't have bash installed or there is no link (or file) /bin/bash you will get the same error as OP (change /bin/bash with whatever shell you use).

Answer (score 3):

You are typing

```
su -sudo
```

and you get the error message

```
su: failed to execute udo: No such file or directory
```

because, in fact, you are trying to invoke [`su` with option `-s` (shell) and argument `udo`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/su). There is no shell "udo", hence the error.

---

To become superuser, either you switch to root, if you have its password:

```
su -
```

or you become root via sudo from your user account, if you have the appropriate rights in the sudoers file:

```
sudo su -
sudo -i
```

Both these two sudo commands give you access as root. The second one, which tells sudo to run a login shell as the target account (root), is more terse and is preferable.

Comment: You ever don't need `sudo su`. This asks `sudo` for root privileges, and then - now running as root - you ask `su` to give you root privileges. For a root login shell use `sudo -i`. For a normal root shell use `sudo -s` (or on some systems, simply `sudo`)

Comment: @roaima Good point, added.